Elegant way to add a link next to the APP name in Django Admin
See photo below, I want to add a link next to "APP1", I had searched google and seems only one way to do it by overriding the admin template app_list.html then see if app name is "APP1" then add the link. It doesn't look like there are sections defined for me to precisely override the particular section, so I would have to copy and paste the whole app_list.html template in my project, this can be a bit of pain for future upgrades when builtin template changed.

        <caption>
          <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section" title="{% blocktranslate with name=app.name %}Models in the {{ name }} application{% endblocktranslate %}">{{ app.name }}</a>
        </caption>

I've tried the verbose_name approach but it didn't want render properly even with mark_safe(), let alone what else this verbose_name will be used and cause more issues, so I am opting out this approach.
verbose_name = mark_safe('APP1 <a href="/somehwere">link</a>')

So apart from overriding the template, is there anything else I can do?

i don't think use mark safe with just "a" tag cause error. why did you think it??

I didn't necessarily mean error but issues. Some where else could be utilising the verbose_name to display just the label and without the link.

Not to mention the  value of verbose_name is wrapped in a link in the template.

APP1 link --> Do you want to apply links to specific letters like this tag?

I suggested another way. Please check my answers!

I understood that you would like to change the app label on your admin page.
The part of the app label that contains data from the Open Source code label.
The Django Administration page generates through AdminSite class.
AdminSite Class
And I confirmed that the method of creating data related to the app label is _build_app_dict.
_build_app_dict
                app_dict[app_label] = {
                    "name": apps.get_app_config(app_label).verbose_name,
                    "app_label": app_label,
                    "app_url": reverse(
                        "admin:app_list",
                        kwargs={"app_label": app_label},
                        current_app=self.name,
                    ),
                    "has_module_perms": has_module_perms,
                    "models": [model_dict],
                }

This code is part of the _build_app_dict, where the "name" value becomes the app label data on the admin page.
That's why you can assign the desired value to the AppConfig class verbose_name variable in apps.py of the app you want to change.
like this.
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
    verbose_name = 'hello world'
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'products'


I have seen in the body of the question that assigning a value to verbose_name causes a different error.
So I thought of a different way.
It's about creating a custom admin site class.
my_project/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
  
  def _build_app_dict(self, request, label=None):
    app_dict = super()._build_app_dict(request, label)
    app_dict["products"]["name"] = "hello world"
    return app_dict

my_project/apps.py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
  default_site = "main.admin.CustomAdminSite"

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    'main.apps.MyAdminConfig', #my_project/apps/my_admin_config_class
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
]


I can see that it works well in my environment.
If you want to label all apps with a specific pattern, you can customize the _build_app_dict method in detail.
I referred to this article.

Template Overriding
On the Admin Index page, the default template that shows the app list is /django/contrib/admin/templates/app_list.html
That's why you can customize the app_list and add it as an additional path for django to find the template.
First allow django to find custom template files.
settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

In the TEMPLATES variable, specify the path to find the template with the DIRS value.
I did the project/templates.
I created a template/admin path folder in the project path and then customized the app_list.html file.
        <caption>
          <!-- <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section" title="{% blocktranslate with name=app.name %}Models in the {{ name }} application{% endblocktranslate %}">{{ app.name }}</a> -->
          {{ app.name }} <a class="section" href="{{ app.app_url }}">link</a>
        </caption>

I don't know if it exactly matches the style you want, but I've separate the link.


Sorry your answer does not add a link next to the app section

I think I need to override the template to separate the link from the app section.I'll put it in the body about how to override the template.
